# JavaScript - Get coordinates of Area Map shapes

Tags: javascript

My HTML element:

```
 <img src ="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets"
usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

How can I used Javascript to get the `coords` of each of the area shapes contained within the `map` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like  this...

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X9KrR/)

```
var coords = [];

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("area"), function (value, index, array) {
    coords.push(value.getAttribute("coords").split(","));
});
```